# RpiZeroW - Can't find `pigpio` while running Python code

Tags: pigpio, gpiozero

I have a python code, using `gpiozero`. When running this code on a RPI-ZEROW it fails, while running same code on RPI3 it succeeds. All installed pretty much the same ( shown checks below ), `pigpio` is at it last version and located in same directories:

relevant part of code ( error comes from line-2):

```
from gpiozero import Button, OutputDevice
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory  <-- This line
from sys import platform, path
import time
```

> on RPI ZEROW:

```
guy@HomePi_Alarm:/ $ sudo apt-get install pigpio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pigpio is already the newest version (1.64-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
guy@HomePi_Alarm:/ $ cd /
guy@HomePi_Alarm:/ $ sudo find -name "pigpio"
./dev/pigpio
./usr/share/doc/pigpio
./opt/pigpio
guy@HomePi_Alarm:/ $ python3 ~/github/Alarm/alarm_watcher.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guy/github/Alarm/alarm_watcher.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pigpio.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pigpio
ImportError: No module named 'pigpio'
guy@HomePi_Alarm:/ $
```

> On RPI3:

```
guy@lab_pi:/ $ sudo apt-get install pigpio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pigpio is already the newest version (1.64-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
guy@lab_pi:/ $ sudo find -name "pigpio"
./opt/pigpio
find: ‘./run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
./dev/pigpio
find: ‘./proc/1247/task/1247/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘./proc/1247/net’: Invalid argument
./usr/share/doc/pigpio
guy@lab_pi:/ $ python3 ~/github/Alarm/alarm_watcher.py 

log start @lab_pi, IP:192.168.2.113, OS:linux, Name:HomePi-AlarmSys monitor
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install the pigpio Python modules.

`sudo apt-get install python-pigpio python3-pigpio`

They will already be installed on "full" versions of Raspbian.

I may have got the module names wrong.  If so use

`apt-cache search pigpio`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pigpio` did the trick. TNX!